# Let $ X $ a set, is $ \mathcal{T}_{\text{Coe}} $ the collection of all subsets $V\in X$ such that $X - V$ is enumerable or all $ X $.

Tags: general-topology

Let $ X $ a set, is $ \mathcal{T}_{\text{Coe}} $ the collection of all subsets $V\in X$ such that $X - V$ is enumerable or all $ X $. Prove define a topology on $ X $

I tried:

$\emptyset\in \mathcal{T}_{\text{Coe}}$ and $X\in  \mathcal{T}_{\text{Coe}}$

but the other  conditions I don't know. Can you give me some ideas for complite all the topologycal conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As $ X-X = \varnothing$ is countable, $X \in \mathcal T_\mathrm{Coe}$, and as $X - \varnothing = X$, $\varnothing \in \mathcal T_\mathrm{Coe}$.
2. Let $\{A_{\lambda \in I} \}$ a family of indexed  elements in $\mathcal T_\mathrm{Coe}$; we want to show that $\bigcup A_{\lambda} $ belongs to $\mathcal T_\mathrm{Coe}$.
   Let $A=\bigcup A_{\lambda} $. Then $ X-A =\bigcap_{\lambda\in I} (X-A_ {\lambda}) $ by the laws of De Morgan. Since each $ A_{\lambda} $ is an element of $\mathcal T_\mathrm{Coe}$, each $ X-A_{\lambda} $ is countable, hence $ \bigcap_{\lambda \in I} (X-A_{\lambda})$ is also countable. The desired conclusion follows.
3. Let $I_{n} = \{1,2, \cdots, n-1, n\}$, let $ \{A_{i}\}_{i\in I_n} $ be a finite family non empty elements $\mathcal T_\mathrm{Coe}$, and let $ A=\bigcap_{i = 1}^{n}A_{i} $.  Then $ X-A = \bigcup_{i = 1}^{n} (X-A_{i}) $ by De Morgan's laws. Now as $ A_ {i}\in\mathcal T_\mathrm{Coe}$ for each $i\in I_{n}$, each $X-A_{i} $ is countable, and as finite unions of countable sets are countable, we can say that $A\in\mathcal T_\mathrm{Coe}$.

Comment: Ugh, forgot to edit this in, but this topology is called either the **countable complement topology** or the **cocountable topology**. Wikipedia link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocountable_topology